# How to generate Alias using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to convert all my title names to a url alias using  SQL query . currently im using sql REPLACE for replace "" (space) with "-" .

But i want to avoid all speacial charactors and spaces between words and convert the title names to aliases

Ex: A B & sons    should be a-b-sons

This is my current query

```
 UPDATE content SET alias = title,alias = LOWER(REPLACE(alias," ", "-"));​
```

is there any option where i can add more speicifed for abocve query for get titles like above with special characters

Ex: **A B & sons**    should be **a-b-sons**

Please advice

Comment: Is this [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]? Surely it cannot be both...

Comment: FYI, that's often called "slug", "semantic URL" or "friendly URL".

Comment: possibly use regular expressions to strip all but numbers and letters and - after replacing space...  RDBMS matters though for how and what functions are available.

Comment: @Mureinik : its mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE()` function multiple time like

```
UPDATE content 
SET alias = LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(alias," ", "-"),"&","-"))
WHERE alias='A B & sons';
```

Comment: will it give outcome with multiple hiphens (-) between words. is it possible to remove "&" using replace wthout adding "-". Pls advice

Comment: Per your post: if alias value is `A B & sons` then the query will result in `a-b-sons`. Try it and see for yourself. Yes, you can replace without adding "-" but you will have provide a replacing character.

Comment: @user3786234, consider accepting the answer if it helped by clicking the check button under voting button.